# iOS AVAudioPlayer not playing

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

This code:

```
NSString *urlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"snd" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlPath];

NSError *err;

AVAudioPlayer* audioPlayerMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&err];

[audioPlayerMusic play];
```

Works just fine.

While this one:

```
NSString *urlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"snd" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlPath];

AVPlayer* audioPlayerMusic = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

[audioPlayerMusic play];
```

Plays nothing!

What's going wrong?

Comment: So merely declaring a variable makes it work?

Comment: What do you mean? Please notice that I just updated the code. I had made a copy/paste mistake.

Comment: see my answer. (first hit on Google for a similar question on SO!)

Comment: @user1423640 Do you have this problem with both `AVAudioPlayer` and `AVPlayer`? (The latter plays videos, not sound.) I edited your question assuming that you meant to discuss `AVAudioPlayer`s specifically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When playing/streaming a remote file, AVPlayer isn't ready to play it - you must wait for it to buffer enough data to start paying, while this is not necessary when using AVAudioPlayer. So, either use AVAudioPlayer, or make AVPlayer notify your class using key-value observing when it's ready to begin playback:

```
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:NULL];
```

And in your class (`self` refers to its instance in the above line):

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            [player play];
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            /* An error was encountered */
        }
    }
}
```